# Which countries allow its international postdoctoral candidates to get their citizenship?

Tags: resident-permit, citizenship

There might be various counties that qualify their postdoc researchers to apply for permanent residency after they finish their contracts. For example, Canada. However, the process is long and the result is not guaranteed as there is no specific category  for postdoc in the country immigration program!

So I was wondering what are the countries that have immigration category  for their postdocs?

Comment: Never heard of anything like that. For the most part a post-doc is just an employee. If anything, there might be a fast-track procedure for people who obtained a Master's degree locally before completing a PhD but not for someone coming from abroad after a PhD.

Comment: Queries about what's "easiest" (not to mention "most guaranteed") will invariably attract opinions, rather than answers. This site seeks questions with declarative answers, not opinions or discussions. I vote to close.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica the question is edited!

Comment: And a good edit it is! I'll withdraw my vote to close.